# 2 TextViews overlapping on each other in constraintlayout

Tags: android, android-layout, constraints, android-constraintlayout, android-cardview

I have below `cardview` layout for my `recyclerview` with 3 views within it namely `ImageView`, `TextView` & `TextView` as below

I am facing a weird problem that even after having proper constraints, its still overlapping both TextViews to each other.

> Problem. : status (TextView) is on right most side. And, name
> (TextView) starts after image which is at left most side. If text data
> is lengthy then name is overlapping over status text.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/cv_background"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/rad_base"
    app:contentPadding="@dimen/s_base">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/left_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/s_base"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu"/>

        <TextView
            style="@style/headline_6"
            android:id="@+id/status"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="LIVE"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/s_base"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/s_base"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="@color/succ"/>

        <TextView
            style="@style/headline_6"
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/col_gray"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/left_image"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/status"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacer_s"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/s_base"
            android:text="Dummy Dummy Dummy Dummy Dummy Dummy"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of your inconsistent, mixed usage of `Start`-`End` and `Left`-`Right`. You should consolidate to `Start` and `End`:

In addition to that, you need to set some more constraints to `left_image` and `status`.

```xml
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/left_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/name"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/s_base"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu"/>

<TextView
    style="@style/headline_6"
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/col_gray"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/left_image"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/status"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/spacer_s"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/s_base"
    android:text="Dummy Dummy Dummy Dummy Dummy Dummy"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

<TextView
    style="@style/headline_6"
    android:id="@+id/status"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="LIVE"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@name"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/s_base"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/s_base"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="@color/succ"/>
```

Comment: No its still same. In fact now, its overlapping on ImageView too

Comment: @VVB Updated. You also need to set some more constraints to `left_image` and `status`.

Comment: With this, its keeping everything at center and expanding to opposite sides when stretches. Ideally, ImageView & Name TextView are at left most side and should expand towards right and vice versa for status TextView which is not happening in above case

Comment: @VVB I can't tell what exactly you images. But there is still many ways to adjust size using `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias` or `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle`.